# How do I debug my C# app and simulate that its running from a specfic folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How do I debug my C# app when it really needs to be running from a specific folder and not from bin/debug? One of the first things my program does for example is determine what set of tools will be presented based on the executable file it finds. But since its running from the debug folder it can't find them. I can add the file there but that seems silly. There has to be a better way. Plus, there's really a bunch of other thighs it does that really requires it to be running from the proper folder eg. Z:\test.

I thought it might be the "Working Directory" setting under the "Debug" tab in Properties but that didn't seem to do anything. I'm using VS2010 and C# btw...

I hope I'm making sense.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the setting.  Sounds like you haven't debugged it yet :)

Comment: Setting the working directory works well for me (and is equivalent to setting `Environment.CurrentDirectory`/`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`). What makes you think it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify another output folder for your build.

Comment: Thank you. While the other suggestion are great too, this does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) to the directory you want to simulate.

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\SimulateThisDirectory\";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("your-path");
```

from your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differ between two things:

- path from which process is started
- current working directory of the process

First one you can't simulate easily. It would probably involve creating a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) or creating some sort of rootkit.

As for second one, your method is fine, and you can check working directory in runtime by using [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)  or set it using [Directory.SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx).

Take note that if you are looking up directory of [executing assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx), you will get path from which process is started.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your program from as normal from the specific directory and then just attach the debugger

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx